# How to extract the keyword from tynt API using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have this API :

https://api.tynt.com/publisher/v1/keyword/inbound?site_guid=c4l6yC_Ler4kAMacwqm_6r&api_key=secretkey&hours=1

how will I extract my inbound keyword from this api and return its value of the keyword to display it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Tynt API](http://www.tynt.com/tynt-api) does not support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) yet, is not implemented "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:***" response header. 
So you should try to read this API using a proxy service like Yahoo (YQL) which is CORS compatible.

Supose we have a global function: readKeywords() which is called from a jQuery getJSON call:

```
// remember to complete it with your secretkey!
var api_url = "http://api.tynt.com/publisher/v1/keyword/inbound?site_guid=c4l6yC_Ler4kAMacwqm_6r&api_key=secretkey&hours=24";

function readKeywords ( data) {
    var keywords = data.query.results.data; // keywords array
    var items = [];

    $.each(keywords, function(index, value) {
        items.push('<li>' + value.json[0] + ': ' + value.json[1] + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
}

$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&q=select * from json where url='" + encodeURIComponent( api_url ) + "' and itemPath='json.data'", readKeywords);
```

This example reads the json response of Tynt from Yahoo's json and writes it to document.body as list where value.json[0] and value.json[1] are the inbound text and counter of each inbound keyword.